# Issues loading Layers with Cyrillic Characters to Geoserver 2.12

Tags: geoserver, encoding

I am running Windows 7. With a  Pure installation of Geoserver 2.12.1 (2.12.0 is the same).

Trying to upload local layer with cyrrilic name:
[image: Geoserver 2.12.4]

Pure installation of Geoserver 2.10.0 (2.11.4 is the same). The similar uploading:
[image]

First image is showing that geoserver after 2.12 version has troubles with cyrrilic layer's names.
Second is showing that if version is under 2.12, problem is gone.

Same data_dir, layers files and pure installations with default settings.

`-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` config is useless.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Could you please expand your question explaining what the two images mean? Image 1, is that what you are currently experiencing, and Image 2 what you are expecting? Have a look at this link it will help you with how to approach asking your question and get the best answers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: did you test the beta of 12 **before** it was released? looks like a bug that user testing would have revealed

Comment: Nope. It's current stable version.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to [open a bug report](http://geoserver.org/issues/) and provide instructions on how to reproduce with test data.
Make it really easy to follow, considering that:

- There is basically no dev on Window
- All core devs speak and use western languages only

Hopefully in time the GeoServer community will be blessed with a russian speaking active contributor (or even better, someone fluent in multiple non western scripts!).